# How to use android USB port to serve as Host?

Tags: java, android, usb, usbserial

I have a Gingerbread Android phone (I'm talking for all v2.3 phones so make and model isn't a choice)

Presently I'm trying to interface it with a USB to TTL/serial converter that would further sent the data to some device (out of scope). So are there any standard API that can enable the android application to send data from its USB port to USB to Serial converter? (ignore the driver issues).

Technically the android act as host and I want to explicitly send data as bytes

Like send 0xAB then send 0xC3 etc.

A clear analogy is the serial communication API in J2SE etc that allows sending data as characters.

Comment: "USB host mode is supported in Android **3.1 and higher**." (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html)

Comment: Goddammit!! :(

isn't there any third party library?

Comment: The open accessory library is available for 2.3.4..